# React Native pull down does not refresh data

Tags: reactjs, json, native

i have a scrollView with a refreshControl. Right now, that is a "On sale" screen that pulls a json file and writes to a hook. (maybe thats my issue?)

It works flawlessly in dev mode, and has been working fine in production up until recently. (past month)

It's like there is a cache that is stuck inside the app. Restarting the app does not help. And i am able to verify that it is not a server issue.

***update***
i removed and re-downloaded the app and now its pulling the correct data. I can change the data and and refresh the screen and its working correctly.

My (non-tech) coworkers are currently running into the issue as well.

Any ideas?

```
  const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      Haptics.notificationAsync(Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Success);

      fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      Haptics.notificationAsync(Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Error);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is giving you an issue and what solutions you've tried.

Comment: it is.. thank you for finding it... i couldn't